# Apache 2 Configure for Nuxt and Laravel on Same Domain Name

Tags: laravel, apache, nuxt.js, apache2

I have Nuxt application that relies on Laravel application for API data. Both are hosted on example.com

**example.com/any-page** have all the public pages

**example.com/api/api-data-endpoint** have all the data

I configured the apache 2 config in such a way that for now only homepage "/" request will be proxied and rest requests will work as it is for testing purpose.

Here's my conf file:

```
ServerName example.com

ProxyPreserveHost On

    
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4001/
```

But after using this conf, all the requests are being proxied, I tried following too:

```
ServerName example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    
    ProxyPass /$ http://127.0.0.1:4001/
    ProxyPassReverse /$ http://127.0.0.1:4001/
```

But still, all requests are being proxied.

Comment: add ``ProxyPass /api/api-data-endpoint !`` after your existing  code. This will exclude the path from being proxied. If you want to exlcude eveyr api endpoint, use ``/api*`` instead of ``/api/api-data-endpoint``